# How to make a PHP curl call to Stanford NLP?

Tags: php, curl, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford NLP local server by a curl call of

```
curl --data "this is a test" http://localhost:9001/?properties={%22prettyPrint%22%3A%22true%22}
```

and everything works perfectly. When I try to use the equivalent curl command in PHP as

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:9001/?properties={%22prettyPrint%22%3A%22true%22}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'this is a test');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

I get an error of

```
string(49) "<h1>400 Bad Request</h1>URISyntaxException thrown"
```

I reckon the problem is the format of `POSTFIELDS`, but still no luck after trying different variations of an array.

Comment: Response is form Stanford NLP. Maybe POSTFIELDS format, yes. Try to url encode, sending: 'this%20is%20a%20test'.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP no it doesn't work. Just out of curiosity, why should we `urlencode` POSTFIELDS when they are not submitted as URL queries?

Comment: Because value set to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS must be a query string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell curl to do a regular post. Just add this line before CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS assigment:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```